# LAMP installation problem

Tags: 14.04, lamp

I want to install LAMP in Ubuntu 14.04, but I have a problem with this command:

```
root@ubuntu:~# sudo nano/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf
```

When run, the error "command not found" occurs.

What should I do to continue this installation?

Comment: You're missing a space between `nano` and `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf`, also `sudo` is not required if you're root: `nano /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf`.

Answer (score 9):

In the command you provided there is a space character missing between `nano` and the following path. Use:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf
```

[`sudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/sudo.8) is a command that takes another command as an argument. In this case that other command should be [`nano`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/nano.1) however if there was no space between the two, shell would try to execute `dir.conf` from `nano/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/` directory. As it does not exist, shell returns an error about the non-existing command.